# Disable Flashing on Taskbar (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Sometimes programs will start flashing on the taskbar until I click on them. For example, when sticky notes opens on startup, I have to click on every note for it to stop flashing. Does anyone know of a way to disable the flashing? I have looked all over and have found nothing that works.

I've tried changing the registry values ForegroundFlashCount to 0 and ForegroundLockTimeout to 0, but they do nothing.

Comment: The default value of ForegroundFlashCount is 7 and it can be set between 1 and 6. Try to change the value of ForegroundFlashCount to 1 to test if the issue still existed. Or please try keep the ForeGroundFlashCount to 0, but change the TimeOut value to 1 to test if the issue still existed.